# InvalidArgument on outputfile in deflate stream

Tags: c#, .net

I want to deflate a file using deflate stream.

Below is the code I am using.

using (oZipper = new DeflateStream(outputFile, CompressionMode.Compress))

Where oZipper is a filestream.

When I step into the line of code above (using (oZipper...), an exception is thrown:

Base stream is not writeable, InvalidArgumentException. Parameter: stream (outputFile, which is a filestream).

Any idea why this is? My code seems to be fine and I'm passing in the right stuff.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you open the FileStream? It sounds like you've opened it for reading rather than writing.

EDIT: So that this is more of an answer...

GSS was opening a FileOutputStream using File.Create, but then *closing* the stream before using it to create the DeflateStream. That stopped DeflateStream from writing to the output stream, hence the problem. Removing the call to close solved the issue.

Comment: I was just looking at the way I opened it. I have this code:

                FileStream outputFile = File.Create(Path.Combine(DestinationFileName, filepath));
                outputFile.Flush();
                outputFile.Close();

Comment: I could try to instantiate a new filestream. Will give that a go, now.

Comment: Just get rid of the call to Close

Comment: (And the call to flush is unnecessary, but it's the close which is causing the problems.)

Comment: Thanks for that! Did the trick. Being denied access to the folder now but that's another issue... Thanks again.